# Visual C++ with a matrix array

Tags: c++, matrix

how can i view all members of some matrix array in my form? 
I can drop as many text field as i need and equalate each of them to each text field. but it's very long way. Is there any easier way?
can i use datagridview tool?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, spawning text fields is not necessarily a long way unless you do it by hand. Basically, it's just spawning and populating a few text fields in a loop, that is, perhaps a few lines of code.

A simple KISS approach (for readonly matrix display) would be a simple text area with the font set to Courier New or any other monospace font. The only thing you'd need to take care of is to format the matrix fields correctly (and truncate respectively pad them as needed).

Comment: well i have an matrix array of size [9][9], so it's pretty long way to write codes for 81 text fields, if there would be some kind of matrix field to show them all i could do in with loop quite easily.

Comment: If you do it programmatically, it doesn't matter much how many elements there are: … `for(int x = 0; x < 9; ++x) { for(int y = 0; y < 9; ++y) { /* add text field at a location that is a function of x and y */ } }`. But I do agree that using one text field per element is perhaps the wrong way here, especially as the number of child windows may be limited.

Comment: i know that there is a way to show a matrix array in Objective C , it's called somekind of radiogroup or something like that, i was wondering if there is something like that in V C++ , it would really help me to write my Sudoku game